# MUltiselect gridview with mouse click

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am developing one custom control in asp.net where I have one gridview with multiple rows.

1.I want user should able to select multiple rows by just clicking on the row. So user should able to select multiple rows by just clicking on row.

2.As I am using same control more places. So at some places ser should able to select only one row and at some places user should able to select multiple rows.

Comment: Consider to accept some answers, that's what how StackoverFlow work :)

Comment: what do you mean by saying  at some places user should able to select only one row and at some places user should able to select multiple rows, Actually what do you want to do? i hope jquery can help you out to sort the problem but before that try to have some some accept ratio.